# Hibernate auto increment field for multiple databases

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, orm

I have a Java object with a field that needs to be auto-incremented in the database.  This field is not a primary key, just a field that needs to be auto-incremented.

My question is what value I need to set this field in my Java object before doing a session.save(Object)? Do I have to set it to NULL?

How would the Hibernate mapping look for this field? This is what I have but its not working:

```
<property name="reportNum" type="java.lang.Long">
 <column name="REPORTNUM"/>
 <generator class="increment"/>
</property>
```

Also the application needs to support both MySQL and SQL Server.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try and keep it as simple as possible and just mark the property with the **insert=false, update=false** attributes.  I've ran into trouble before using the @Generated annotation with named queries, but insert/update=false has always worked as advertised.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use a `<generator>` for a non `id` field. I can think of two possible solutions here.

#### Option 1

Have the property generated by the database (either using an auto-increment column<sup>1</sup> or a trigger) and map it as generated property (see [5.6. Generated properties](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/mapping.html#mapping-generated)):

```
<property name="reportNum" type="java.lang.Long" generated="insert">
  <column name="REPORTNUM"/>
</property>
```

This tells Hibernate that the given property value is generated on insert (and Hibernate will read it after the insert to value the entity).

#### Option 2

Create an entity with only an ID attribute. When you need a new value you simply create a new instance and save it to the database. Then, you set the generated ID in your entity.

<sub><sup>1</sup> DISCLAIMER: I didn't check if this is possible for a non pk column.</sub>

Comment: Thank you for pointing that generated="insert" attribute.  I will include that in my hibernate mapping file.